# Catching Warnings in Function skimage.img_as_uint

Tags: python, warnings, scikit-image

I tried both warnings.catch_warnings() and the input parameter `force_copy`
both failed to catch conversion warnings

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
import warnings

mm = np.ones([55,55],dtype=np.float32)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
     dd = skimage.img_as_uint(mm,force_copy=True)
```

gives

```
XXX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:130: UserWarning: Possible precision loss
when converting from float32 to uint16.format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line, `warnings.simplefilter('ignore')`:

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage
import warnings

mm = np.ones([55,55],dtype=np.float32)
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    dd = skimage.img_as_uint(mm,force_copy=True)
```

See the [Python documentation for "temporarily suppressing warnings"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) for more information.